# TextToSpeech's UtteranceProgressListener is not called when Talkback interrupts

Tags: android, text-to-speech, talkback

I have an `UtteranceProgressListener` set on a `TextToSpeech` instance. It is called and it works well, **but** when a user is using Talkback, it may interrupt my speech request and my `UtteranceProgressListener` is never called (not even `onError`). Is this a flaw on Android's side or am I doing something wrong?

My code:

```
final String utteranceId = generateUtteranceId();
tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStart(String s) {
        if(utteranceId.equals(s)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStart");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDone(String s) {
        if(utteranceId.equals(s)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onDone");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String s) {
        if(utteranceId.equals(s)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onError");
        }
    }
});

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    tts.speak(textToSpeech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, utteranceId);
} else {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, utteranceId);
    tts.speak(textToSpeech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, map);
}
```

Comment: Can you replicate this if you bind to a different TTS engine than Talkback uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the method `UtteranceProgressListener#onStop(String utteranceId, boolean interrupted)` does capture interrupted speech events. I didn't notice before because it's not an abstract method, so Android Studio didn't automatically insert it when writing an implementing class. Whenever a screen reader interrupts the current speech, a call to this method will be made with the interrupted argument set to true.

Comment: How do u know when to continue the tts again?

Comment: I guess you shouldn't try to make further speech utterances to the user. Otherwise the app may seem annoying. If you still want to enable the user to listen, make the speech utterance available as an on-screen item with the text.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. The app i'm working on has tts to read books out loud. I'm not sure what the expected behaviour should be. If i continue tts it might seem annoying as you say, but if i let talkback handle everything the reading settings from my app won't not applied to it and that might seem annoying aswell

Comment: See if this applies to your case: In the Google Play Books app you can set the app to read the text aloud and also has talkback compatibility. The way it works is by actually waiting for a couple of seconds after Talkback finishes and then proceeds to keep reading. This is kind of opposite to what I said before, but at least allows some breath between Talkback and your own speech utterance.